# Правильно ли, что слово "ободренный" является прилагательным, а слово "просиявший" - причастием?

Tags: причастия, прилагательные, недопустимая-метка, морфология

Ободренный и просиявший надеждами, он отлучился на несколько дней.

Comment: Человека посетили надежды, они его ободрили и он ими - просиял! Все причастившиеся - временно отлучились)

Comment: Надо сказать: "исполненный надежд", тогда всем понравится. Тоже метафора, но получившая постоянную прописку в языке. А если он эти надежды излучает - как об этом сказать? Дерзкий grantum, подскажите решение.

Comment: "Просиявший  надеждами" просто  неудачная  конструкция.  А  может  и  метафора  неудачная.

Answer (score 7):

А почему ободренный - не причастие? Ободренный - тот, кого ободрили. Страдательное причастие прошедшего времени. Хотя по контексту, в зависимости от смысла, можно назвать и прилагательным, если вы не видите здесь процессуального признака и можете подобрать синонимы-прилагательные, например бодрый, уверенный.

Comment: Лишний раз подтверждает мысль, которую я уж лет двадцать "двигаю в массы" - с техз пор как прочерпнул её у Аванесова. Различия между причастием и отглагольным прилагательным - не в грамматике, а в головах тех, кто это грамматику изобретает.

Answer (score 2):

Оба причастия. К тому же у слова "ободренный" есть приставка. И его всё-таки ободрили. "Обрадованный" же причастие.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что не стоит считать "ободренный" прилагательным, для этого необходима пара "причастие (прямое значение) и прилагательное (переносное значение)". Например, выдержанный  чай (причастие)и выдержанный (=спокойный)человек (отпричастное прилагательное). "Ободренный" обозначает признак как действие, завершенное на момент речи, переносного значения нет.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Автор задает сходные вопросы - возможно считает, что страдательное причастие всегда переходит в прилагательное, а действительное причастие не переходит. Но это не так. Адъективизация возможна для  различных причастий, но при определенных условиях.

Comment: >Адъективизация возможна для различных причастий, но при определенных условиях.  
  
Вот с этого места поподробнее, пожалуйста (С).

Comment: Дорогой behemothus, я же наизусть не помню, придется книжку искать. Но что не сделаешь для Вас! Ну вот она. Признаки адъективизации причастий: утрата зависимых слов, употребление в переносном значении - ну Вы это всё знаете. Вот интересно:  вхождение в терминологию (пишущая машинка), способность образовывать степени сравнения и определительное наречие: дискуссия стала оживленнее, подействовать ошеломляюще, подробности потрясающи.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказали выше, оба слова являются причастием.